# Rewrite macro as c++ function?

Tags: c++, macros

i want to rewrite this macro as a c++ function.

```
#define SAFE_BUFFER_DELETE(buf)     { if(buf != NULL) { buffer_delete(buf); buf = NULL; } }
```

Additionl info  http://paste.ubuntu.com/13940691/
abot .header file

```
    void buffer_read(LPBUFFER buffer, void * buf, int bytes) {
        thecore_memcpy(buf, buffer->read_point, bytes);
        buffer_read_proceed(buffer, bytes);
    }

void buffer_delete(LPBUFFER buffer) {
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    buffer_reset(buffer);

    int size = buffer->mem_size;

    int pool_index = buffer_get_exac_pool_index(size);
    if (pool_index >= 0) {
        BUFFER** buffer_pool = normalized_buffer_pool + pool_index;
        buffer->next = *buffer_pool;
        *buffer_pool = buffer;
    } else {
        free(buffer->mem_data);
        free(buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's stopping from doing so?

Comment: What types are acceptable for `buf`?

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: what's the input argument type of `buffer_delete`?

Comment: Btw, there's no need to check for `NULL`. `delete`ing a null pointer is a no-op (assuming that's what you do in your `buffer_delete` function).

Comment: If you have other macros like this, you should be aware that `if (foo) SAFE_BUFFER_DELETE(buf); else doSomething();` will not compile.

Comment: EDITED main question, with aditional info

Comment: C++ has references - could subsume the extra functionality of setting the parameter to null in the actual function

Comment: `SAFE_BUFFER_DELETE` - wishful thinking.

Comment: Why are you using `free` and not `delete`?

Comment: @EdHeal  free to free memory. Should i use delete?

Comment: C++ `new/delete` or `new[], delete[]` - C `malloc/free`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the source code of `buffer_delete`, it becomes obvious that the check for `if (buf != NULL)` is completely superfluous. So get rid of it.

Once this is done, the macro does two things.

- call `buffer_delete` on its argument
- assign `NULL` to its argument

How to do the first thing in a function is clear. In C++, a function may also accept an argument as reference and hence can modify it.  Your function would look like this.

```
inline void
safe_delete_buffer(LPBUFFER& buf)
{
  buffer_delete(buf);
  buf = nullptr;
}
```

I am assuming that `LPBUFFER` is a `typedef` for some pointer type.

Whether the behavior of such function is useful and intuitive to the user is another question.

Comment: typedef struct buffer* LPBUFFER;
 yes , it's a typedef